# Loading Nib file To NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdata, nib

I'm having trouble loading a Nib, generated by:

```
ibtool MyNib.xib --compile MyNib.nib
```

I have tried using the full path for everything.  I've tried --output-format human-readable-text and binary1.

This is the code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyView" ofType:@"nib"];

NSFileManager* fs = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

BOOL isDir;
// Debugger shows this to be true
BOOL exists = [fs fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];

NSError* error;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path
                                      options: nil
                                        error: &error];
```

I check the file exists, which it does.  But it fails to create the NSData.  The error contains this information:

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x7c6d9c0 {NSFilePath=/Users/onbek/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/FE56BA5C-9333-4E7B-A13C-137E0357519B/MyApp.app/MyView.nib, NSUnderlyingError=0x7c70ad0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"}

These are the permissions for the file:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 onbek  staff    136 26 Jun 19:56 MyView.nib
```

And its contents:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 onbek  staff  5275 26 Jun 19:56 objects.nib
-rw-r--r--  1 onbek  staff  5983 26 Jun 19:56 runtime.nib
```

I have searched and have been unable to find why I am unable to create the NSData object.  My initial information I used to find this out was on http://www.indelible.org/ink/nib-loading/ Loading Raw nib Data.

I have tried many things all of which I tried after performing a clean build:

Fiddling with the permissions.
I tried looking in the derived data folder for my project, copying a nib that Xcode had built, copying it and seeing if I could get that to create a NSData object.  It didn't.
Deleting derived data and resetting the simulator ad nauseam.
Prayer.

My goal is to be able to load a Nib from a arbitrary location (downloaded that is).

Comment: Could be a sandboxing issue. Have you tried using the URL-based methods (i.e. `-[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]` and `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]`) instead of path-based ones?